# Keras kernel_initializer must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

I noticed that assigning the keras.initializer inside a layer results in an error claiming that the variable initializers must either be wrapped in an `init_scope` or callable. However, I fail to see how my below use-case is different than the example provided [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/). Is there a workaround of this issue or am I making some obvious error in using keras initializers?

Here is the minimal example that I could come up with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras import initializers

inputs_test=Input((512,512,3))
initializer_truncated_norm =  initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0, stddev=0.02)
deconv_filter = Conv2DTranspose(3, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer_truncated_norm)(inputs_test)
model2 = Model(inputs=inputs_test, outputs=deconv_filter)
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
model2.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
model2.summary()
```

Here is the exact error that I get when running such function

> ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped
> in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file
> a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your example without errors. `tf==2.3.1, keras==2.4.0`.
Also tried it with `tf==2.0` in Colab and it worked OK again. I suggest you to upgrade to the latest TF and try again.

Also change your imports from `from keras` to `from tensorflow.keras`

If still fails - post the full error stack here and version info.

Comment: Changing the imports solved the problem! My version of tensorflow is 2.0.0, so I think there was no need to update tensorflow. Interesting that from keras fails on my version (and machine) though. However this is a good guide in case someone else runs into this issue. Thank you so much! If you do not mind me asking, what incited the import change suggestion?

Comment: Glad to help. Keras is now an integral part of TF.  When I see `import from keras` - it is often some older code. Also there may be a risk  that one has an older version of Keras hanging around and importing it directly (vs from TF) may cause some odd incompatibility issues.